# How to add a default CSS class for one kind of elements in Hugo?

Tags: html, css, hugo, static-generator

I'm modifying a theme I found for Hugo and I wondered how I can add a css class to the tables in the HTML code generated.
I want to use a css framework and I would like if the tables have`class="u-full-width"`, I know I can edit the css codes but I think there must be a clever way.

Somthing that automatically add the class attributes to every tables in the HTML generated code.

Comment: Do you need to add `class="u-full-width"` to tables generated by users in the .md files, or just to tables generated by the theme itself? Also, what's the theme that you're modifying?

Comment: I understand you need shortcodes : https://zwbetz.com/style-a-markdown-table-with-bootstrap-classes-in-hugo/

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little digging, I assume you're using the `SKELETON` CSS Framework?

I think your best option here is to wrap your tables with vanilla markup, and add a single line of CSS:

```
<div class="u-full-width">
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
</div>
```

... with your CSS like so:

```
div.u-full-width > table {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... or alternatively, you can *inherit* the styles from `SKELETON`:

```
div.u-full-width > table {
  width: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript you can simply use `var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table")` as your selector.

Then add the class using `for`

here is the code

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
        len = tables !== null ? tables.length : 0,
        i = 0;
    for(i; i < len; i++) {
        tables[i].className += " u-full-width"; 
    }
}
function addclass(){
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
        len = tables !== null ? tables.length : 0,
        i = 0;
    for(i; i < len; i++) {
        tables[i].className += " u-not-full-width"; 
    }
}
```

```css
table {
border:1px solid #000;
width:100%;
height:300px;
}
td {
border:1px solid red;
}
.u-full-width{
background-color:blue;
}
.u-not-full-width{
background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addclass();">Add class to all tables</button>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table >
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table >
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Yes you can

Comment: I would like to not use javascript, is it possible?

Comment: yes you can try the code above, and give me an upvote and mark it as answred please :)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort (I'll upvote your answer) but this is not what I mean, I know that using javascript I can do that but I want to change the html generated by Hugo.

Comment: you can make an author but my answer is what you asked for.
you want to add a class automaticly to all table generated by Hugo ^^

Comment: Market as resolved then i would help you in your next question, do it for the community

Comment: "I wondered how I can add a css class to the tables **in the HTML code generated**"
I'm not an english native speaker but I think I've been clear; correct your answer and I'll be happy to mark it as resolved

Comment: if you added this script anywhere in your code, in the footer if you would like, then all the **tabels  in the HTML code generated** would have that class, i guarantee it :)

Comment: There i added a button to do that